# Trouble Controlling Powershell Workflow Timeout

Tags: powershell, workflow-foundation, powershell-3.0, workflow-activity

I have a powershell workflow which is generating the error:

> "The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of
>   00:00:30.  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion
>   of a longer timeout"

The workflow script is:

```
Workflow Test-Me (){
    Param
    (
        $Path = "c:\temp"
    )

    $Files = InlineScript{
                Get-ChildItem -Path $using:Path -File -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt ((get-date).AddDays(-$using:Days))} | Select FullName
             }

    Foreach -parallel ($File in $Files){
        sequence{
            InlineScript{
                Remove-Item -Path $using:File.FullName -force -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
            } -PSActionRunningTimeoutSec 300
        }
    }
}
```

The line that generates the error is the `InlineScript` which handles the `remove-item` operation.  It runs and works for 30 seconds after it reaches the operation before it quits with the error referenced above.  I've added the `-PSActionRunningTimeoutSec` parameter to the `InlineScript` and that didn't impact the error.  I've also set the workflow common parameters as follows:

```
-PSRunningTimeoutSec = 300
-PSElapsedTimeoutSec = 0
```

I call the workflow cmdlet with the following process:

```
PS C:\> . "c:\path\to\Test-Me.ps1"
PS C:\> Test-Me -PSRunningTimeoutSec 300 -PSElapsedTimeoutSec 0
```

There's obviously a timeout somewhere that I can't find/don't know about but powershell isn't being specific.  What timeout did I miss and how do I change it?

References:

[about_WorkflowCommonParameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj129719.aspx)

[PowerShell Workflows: Using Parameters](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/30/powershell-workflows-using-parameters.aspx)

[Syntactic Differences Between Script Workflows and Scripts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574140.aspx)

[about_InlineScript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649082.aspx)